# Property @value Spring

Tags: java, spring

In spring, we can use `@value` annotation to refer a property value that is defined in the property file. In this approach, the way it would be something like

1. To have a separate property file and define the property name and value
2. To list this property class path in a spring config file
3. Finally referring the value in a class with @value annotations as 
   `@value("{key_name}") String abc;`

Other hand , we can try simply define that property value as a constant in the class something like the below and use it in the class.

```
public static final String key_name = "1q2w3e";
```

Since we have this simple approach, why we are using `@value` annotation approach as defined above.

Please help me to understand in detailed about it.

Answer (score 2):

Using configuration values from external sources (e.g. property files) has many advantages. Some of them:

1. You can change the configuration without recompiling your code.
2. You can have multiple instances of the same binary-code running with different configuration values.
3. Configuration values can not only come from property-files that are bundled with your application, but from different sources like system-properties, environment-values, a database or any other custom source.

As a general rule only use constant values for things that will never change like the value of PI.

Answer (score 0):

There's a big disadvantage in using the second method. Think of a scenario where you changed the language. If you were relying on the first approach you'd have to go through each class and change the value assigned to **key_name**. Now, if you were using the second method you'd only have to change the value assigned to **key_name** in one place, and that's in the properties file which is much simpler and make things more manageable.